# How to get the IQueryable<T> extension methods instead of the IEnumerable<T> extensions?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, extension-methods, ienumerable, iqueryable

*Probably really simple so please excuse my ignorance...*

To my knowledge, there are a couple flavours of the `Where()` extension method:

[`Queryable.Where<TSource> Method (IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource, Boolean>>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx)

[`Enumerable.Where<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx)

*Both of the above extensions are housed in the `System.Linq` namespace, so that I can do `Where()` at all is hopefully proof enough that I've imported the correct namespace - or is there another namespace I need for IQueryable extensions?*

I understand that [`IQueryable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) inherits from [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) but why can't I get the `IQueryable<T>` extensions?

```
class Test
{
    IQueryable<Test> SomeMethod(Func<T, bool> criteria)
    {
        return new List<Test> { new Test() }.AsQueryable().Where(criteria); // compiler error converting IEnumerable<T> to IQueryable<T>
    }

}
```

As shown above, there *should* be an extension method available that returns IQueryable?  Why is it resolving to the IEnumerable Extensions?

Comment: Please describe, what you really want to do. Your code doesn't even compile: *Extension method must be static*. You tried to declare a non-static extension method in a non-static class.

Comment: My mistake - I'll correct it but the answer was obvious as expected - I was passing `Func<T, bool>` forcing the IEnumerable<T> extension when what I needed was of course `Expression<T, bool>`.  NOw if only I stopped to read all those lovely links I posted...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Queryable.Where Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535040.aspx) expects an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` (i.e. an expression tree representing a lambda), not a `Func<T, bool>` (a lambda itself).

This works:

```
IQueryable<Test> ApplyCriteria(IQueryable<Test> queryable,
                               Expression<Func<Test, bool>> criteria)
{   //                              ↑
    return queryable.Where(criteria);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I knew it would be obvious =)

Answer (score 4):

`IQueryable<T>.Where()` only works with `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` as predicate argument.

Comment: ulrichb - you and @dtb both posted the correct answer at the same time, but he was first to expand on it so I'll mark his as the answer.  Thank you though!!